# How to Unpark a Call

Tags: c#, asterisk, asteriskami

I want to hold/unhold my calls using Asterisk AMI. I have used Park AMI Action. Then, My phone disconnects, and Senders phone plays a music. How to Unpark this Call ? Can anybody help me Please ?

```
  UnParkAction upac = new UnParkAction(channel, channel1, "360000");
  ManagerResponse rr = ApplicationVariables.manager.SendAction(upac); //Sending it to Manager COnnection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Redirect AMI command.

This solves the unparking issue but with a difference that the initiator will still need to answer a call. In other words he does not fully retrieve the call without any action at all.

**In more detail:**

When you park the call you need to have both channels:

> (1) Channel to be parked
>
> (2) Channel that makes the park

Store in a static variable **(1)**.

Then when you finished parking do the following:

Initiate redirect call from the Channel parked (essentially what you have stored) and as destination, your number.

Example URL:

```
https://<YOUR AMI URL>?action=Redirect&channel=" + channelParked + "&context=" + context + "&priority=1&Exten=" + myPhoneNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you parking call it say you parking lot id.

You have call that lot id to catch phone.

If you want just hold it use Musiconhold command.

If you want more controlable automated parking-like setup, use transfer to conference on musiconhold extension.